# How to add a trademark or copyright symbol without the number pad on a keyboard?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, hotkeys

Earlier I had a laptop with a number pad. Therefore, I was able to insert the trademark symbol easily with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+0153 keys.

However, my new HP Omen laptop does not have a number pad. When I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+0153 using the standard number keys on the keyboard, nothing happens.

In this situation, how do I add a trademark symbol using keyboard shortcuts? Or copyright symbol?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Try AutoCorrect

(c) will produce the copyright symbol ©.

(tm) will produce the trademark symbol ™.

- Here is MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page on [Exploiting AutoCorrect](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/AutoCorrect.htm).
- Here is my page on [Boilerplate in Word](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoCorrect) that covers AutoCorrect.

These come built into Word's definitions.

Comment: Thank you. If I want to use the trademark or copyright symbol on a website form, then how do I do that?

Comment: You tagged this for MS Word and that is the solution in Word. Once you have the symbol, you can certainly copy and paste into a form. The symbols shown in my answer were copied and pasted from Word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Character Map to find the symbols, copy and paste them on your app. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type charmap. Press OK.

**Trademark**

On the "Go to Unicode" box, enter `2122`. Click on Select, then Copy. You can now paste te symbol in your app.

[image]

**Copyright**

On the "Go to Unicode" box, enter `00A9`. Click on Select, then Copy. Paste it in your app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you know the Unicode reference, you can also just type it in your document (using the standard keyboard), and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>. For example, for the trademark symbol, type **2122**, and then while the cursor is still after the final 2, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

The only caveat is that the character immediately before the first digit of the Unicode reference can't be a hexadecimal character (0-9, A-F); otherwise, Word interprets it as part of the Unicode reference. (For example if the preceding word ends in an e, Word will try to insert the character that has the Unicode reference e2122.) I usually insert a space, insert the character, and then delete the space.

There's also a default AutoCorrect entry defined in Word. Assuming that you haven't disabled AutoCorrect in Word Options, if you type **(c)**, Word should replace it with ©; if you type **(tm)**, Word should replace it with ™.

Comment: Hello. Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Suppose I do not use Word and want to use the symbol in Google Chrome instead. How do I insert the trademark symbol in the browser?

Comment: @Shiva. Sorry, I have no idea. I don't use Chrome. I presume you would instead have to follow the instructions provided by Baa or Reddy Lutonadio in other answers. However, if your question isn't actually about Word after all, you should change the tags that are attached to the question. Those tags indicate that you're asking about Word/Office.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 10 and 11 you can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+`;` to open the emoji menu which also has all symbols on it.

[image: Emoji Menu]

From here you can search for Trademark to get the ™ Emoji:

[image: Trademark]

Or click onto Symbols and you can scroll through them in categories:

[image: Symbols menu]

[image: Symbols menu 2]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your keyboard - specifically the 7, 8, 9, U, I, O, J, K, L, and M keys. Do they have small numbers printed on them? If so, you can use those keys in conjunction with NumLock and the Alt key (and possibly the FN key depending on your laptop) to function like a number pad for entering alt codes.

A quick Google search found the following page that explains in detail (didn't see the point in plagiarizing their work here):
[https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/windows/alt-codes/laptop/#:~:text=From%20user%3A,open%20a%20calculator%2Dlike%20keypad](https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/windows/alt-codes/laptop/#:%7E:text=From%20user%3A,open%20a%20calculator%2Dlike%20keypad)